# How to rename my originalname when using multer memoryStorage?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, uuid, multer

i am trying to rename my file originalname when using multer memoryStorage. I am using multer to upload an array of files and when i console.log(req.files) i get:

```
{
fieldname: 'images',
originalname: 'snake.jpg',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
buffer: <Buffer ff d8 38134 more bytes>,
size: 38184
}
```

The reason i want to rename my originalname is i am storing the images in AWS S3 and if the images have the same name it gets updated not added as a new image.

I have tried doing so by adding the date next to the originalname when storing in database but then originalname does not change when the images get added in bucket.

Here is my code:

**posts.js**

```
const storage=multer.memoryStorage()

const upload = multer({
storage: storage,
limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 },
});

router.post(
"/",
[    upload.array("images", config.get("maxImageCount")),
 imageResize,
],
async (req, res) => {
const paths = await req.files.map((file) => ({ originalName: file.originalname + "-" + new 
              Date().toISOString() + "-" + uuidv4()}));
await Post.create({
    title: req.body.title,
    userId: req.body.userId,
    Post_Images: paths.map((x) => ({ images: x.originalName })),
},
{ 
include: [Post_Image] }).then(
res.status(201).send())
```

**imageResize.js**

```
const sharp = require("sharp");
require("dotenv").config();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
region:process.env.AWS_REGION
})

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
const images = [];

const resizePromises = req.files.map(async (file) => {
console.log(file)

await sharp(file.buffer)
  .resize(2000)
  .jpeg({ quality: 50 })
  .toBuffer()
  .then(resized=>s3.upload({
    Bucket:process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Key:file.originalname + "_full.jpg",
    Body:file.buffer,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  }).promise()),

  await sharp(file.buffer)
  .resize(100)
  .jpeg({ quality: 30 })
  .toBuffer()
  .then(resized=>s3.upload({
    Bucket:process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Key:file.originalname + "_thumb.jpg",
    Body:file.buffer,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  }).promise())

 images.push(file.originalname);

  });

await Promise.all([...resizePromises]);

req.images = images;

next();
};
```

in other words, i am trying to change my `originalname` in my req.files to
`originalname + "-" + new Date().toISOString() + "-" + uuidv4()`

OR

How do i keep the uuid and the date the same in my posts.js and imageResize.js?

Comment: can you log paths after this `const paths = await req.files.map((file) => ({ originalName: file.originalname + "-" + new 
              Date().toISOString() + "-" + uuidv4()}));`

Comment: @Alex when i console.log(paths) i get [
  {
    originalName: 'snake.jpg-2020-12-28T11:18:22.666Z-89757b75-b0f3-44a8-8b1d-c655167ac705'
  }
]

Comment: You renamed files after resizing and storing to S3. Rename files while resizing before uploading to S3

Comment: @Anatoly when i rename the files in my posts.js it does not reflect in my imageResize.js since images pass through the imageResize middleware first before storing in db. currently images in my S3 have different uuid and date than in my database. instead of renaming how do i make the uuid and the date the same in both files?

Comment: That's why you should rename them in a middleware before you start to process them in `posts.js`

Comment: and when i rename in the middleware will it update in the posts.js?